# BufferedReader string memory leak?

Tags: java, string, memory, bufferedreader

I'm working on a project for AP Computer Science where we are essentially making a library, where you can add customers and books, check out books to customers, etc, and we have to be able to read/write to a CSV. I'm having some trouble with this code (this is only part of it, and I am pretty sure the rest of it works, the whole thing is approaching 600 lines, total):

```
public void readForBook()  {    
    try{ 
        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("book.csv"));

        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        while (dataRow != null){
            String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(", ");
            int tbuid = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[0]);
            String t_title = dataArray[1];
            String tfirst = dataArray[2];
            String tlast = dataArray[3];
            String tdescription = dataArray[4];
            String tisbn = dataArray[5];
            String tdpurchase = dataArray[6];
            String tcopyrightyear = dataArray[7];
            double tcost = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[8]);
            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();
            int crYear = Integer.parseInt(tcopyrightyear);

            Book tempBook = new Book(tbuid, t_title, tfirst, tlast, tdescription, tisbn, tdpurchase, crYear, tcost);
            BookList.add(tempBook);
        }
        CSVFile.close();
    } catch(IOException fnfe) { 
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }
}
public void readForCustomer(){      
    try{ 
        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("customer.csv"));

        String customerRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        customerRow = CSVFile.readLine();
        while (customerRow != null){
            String[] customerCSVArray = customerRow.split(", ");
            int tcuid = Integer.parseInt(customerCSVArray[0]);

            String temp_zip = customerCSVArray[7];
            int tzip = Integer.parseInt(temp_zip);
            String temp_balance = customerCSVArray[8];
            double tbalance = Double.parseDouble(temp_balance);


            Customer tempCustomer = new Customer(tcuid, customerCSVArray[1], customerCSVArray[2], customerCSVArray[3], customerCSVArray[4], customerCSVArray[5], customerCSVArray[6], tzip, tbalance, customerCSVArray[9]);
            CustomerList.add(tempCustomer);
        }
        CSVFile.close();
    } catch(IOException fnfe) { 
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here's the issue: the first one, readForBook, works perfectly, however, readForCustomer is the one that has the "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:39)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:312)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.<init>(StreamDecoder.java:231)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.<init>(StreamDecoder.java:211)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:50)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:57)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:590)
at Customer.<init>(Customer.java:6)
at Library.readForCustomer(Library.java:219)
at Library.importFromTextFile(Library.java:170)
at Library.mainMenu(Library.java:149)
at Library.<init>(Library.java:17)
at runIt.main(runIt.java:3)
```

I ran a heap dump through VisualVM, and it's saying that there are a large amount of string instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you have to keep calling `CSV.readLine ()`. You call it only once **outside of the loop**, which means you'll end up with an infinite loop and possibly a full heap.

Answer (score 2):

Change the loop to:

```
  while ((customerRow = CSVFile.readLine()) != null){
     //...
  }
```

And remove the line above: `dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();`